# .net mvc 5.2.3 does not work correctly in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5.2

After upgrading my .net mvc project to 5.2.3, it does not have nice features like validating view/action names and linking to them.

here are my project type guids

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

which should mean web application + C# and probably is correct

I have Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

.net version is 4.5.51641

and tools which are probably related

- ASP.NET and Web Tools   12.4.51016.0
- ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.21001.0
- ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.21010.0

do i need some additional extension or is there some secret project guid for mvc 5.2.3?

Comment: Try installing Web Essentials?

Comment: i have it installed, but web essentials is not related to mvc project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out to be a resharper issue
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-433112

have been using this tool for so long it seemed natural to have this kind of intellisense and started to blame visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the package. Then clean the solution and reinstall it again.

Comment: no luck. does mvc 5 projects have these features in your VS?